# How to get representative samples from high dimensional data (with lots of features)

Tags: r, sampling

Now I have a dataset with regards to the survey. It has ~150000 records and ~120 variables. Variables are listed as city,county,street,age,employed or not,income etc.

I want to take the random 5000 representative samples. I am considering using stratified sampling or cluster sampling . A few questions are as below.

1. For the stratified sampling, how to select the variables to stratified on since there are a lots of dimensions in the dataset?
2. There are several packages in R for stratified sampling. Which one will give us more reprentative samples?
3. Which test should I use to see if the samples are representative of the population.

Comment: These all seem like methods questions, not programming questions. I'd suggest asking on Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your question will probably be more warmly received if you demonstrate some research effort in the question.  I googled "compare r packages for stratified sampling" and got this research paper [R packages for optimal stratified sampling: a review and compared evaluation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327791484_R_packages_for_optimal_stratified_sampling_a_review_and_compared_evaluation) as the first hit - I'd suggest at least skimming that paper and asking on forums like this about any questions that remain, rather than essentially asking for that paper.